# How to create a link between these two tables?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have two tables that I have to fill in after scanning a NFC tag.

```
SCAN:
-IdScan
-Data
-Date
-Geolocation

-GEOLOCATION:
-Latitude
-Longitude
-Country
-PostalCode
-etc.
```

My question is : how to link these two tables ?
When I insert a new scan into Scan table, I'd like to create a link between Scan's `location` field and table `LOCATION`
I heard about foreign key but I don't know if it's useful in this case...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (Geolocation) in SCAN table has the values Latitude and Longitude. Please refer to this link(though it's PostgreSQL, concepts should be applicable to any RDBMS too like sqlite. 
[DDL Constraints for Foreign Key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

TL;DR: A foreign key constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values appearing in some row of another table. We say this maintains the referential integrity between two related tables.
So in case you want to make (Geolocation) as Foreign Key - You must find a Primary key in Geolocation table so may be adding a date and making (date,lat,lon) as a composite primary key would make it a fit for referential integrity.